# Declaration of a new class element

Tags: c#

I have some problems with this code piece. I would appreciate some help.

```
class Alpha{
  string Name;
  public Alpha(string name){
    this.Name = name;
  }
}
class Beta{
  Alpha[] alpha_array;
  string Name;
  public Beta(Alpha[] alpha_array, string name){
    this.Alpha_array = alpha_array;
    this.Name = name;
  }
}

static void Main(){
  Beta betas = new Beta[10];
  for(int i = 0; i < betas.Length; i++){
    betas[i] = new Beta(new Alpha[1], "Bob");
    betas[i].alpha_array = new Alpha("George");
    Console.WriteLine(betas[i].alpha_array.Name);
  }
}
```

What is the problem here?
I would use this code but when I try to acces the alpha_array, the betas array doesn't have an alpha_array element. How to do this, I can't figure out it by myself.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's private. All properties in a class is by default private. You can change it to internal or public. Example : `public Alpha[] alpha_array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few errors in your code:

All fields are `private` if you don't specify an access modifier. You should make them `public`. Example:

```
class Alpha{
  public string Name;
  public Alpha(string name){
    this.Name = name;
  }
}

class Beta{
  public Alpha[] alpha_array;
  public string Name;
  public Beta(Alpha[] alpha_array, string name){
    this.Alpha_array = alpha_array;
    this.Name = name;
  }
}
```

You're trying to assign an instance of `Alpha` to an `Array` of `Alpha`:

```
betas[i].alpha_array = new Alpha("George");
```

I think what you want is the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < betas.Length; i++){
    betas[i] = new Beta(new Alpha[]{ new Alpha("George")}, "Bob");
    Console.WriteLine(betas[i].alpha_array[0].Name); // prints George
}
```

Comment: Implicit instance of array, it migth be a little bit confusing for beginners

Comment: What do you mean by `implicit instance`? I specifically did not use an `implicitly` typed array. I used an Array initializer shorthand.

Comment: Yeah, I had the class as public in the real code but not their variables, I think this will solve my pdoblem, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you.